# Как бы выглядел такой React код без шаблоной строки и без условного (тернарного) оператора а с if else?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как бы выглядел такой React код без шаблоной строки и без условного (тернарного) оператора а был с обычным if-else? Прошу ссылки на документацию не бросать, читал, хочу визуально увидеть пример на своем коде, а не на чужом.

```
<button className={`tablinks ${i === active ? 'active' : ''}`}
            onClick={openTab}
            data-index={i}
>{n.title}</button>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Можно создать переменную:

```
let buttonClass;
if(active===i){
  buttonClass = 'active';
}else{
  buttonClass = '';
}
...
<button 
  className={'tablinks '+buttonClass}
  onClick={openTab}
  data-index={i}
>{n.title}</button>
```

Можно попробовать функцией:

```
<button 
  className={'tablinks '+(function isActive(active,i){
    if(active===i){
      return 'active';
    }else{
      return '';
    }
  })(active,i)}
  onClick={openTab}
  data-index={i}
>{n.title}</button>
```

Comment: кхм, кхм, вы реакт забыли...

Comment: Допустим. Как правильно?

Comment: а зачем Вы тогда отвечаете на вопрос, если не знаете методологии реакта?